# C++ build system - remote compile & link option

Tags: c++, build

is there any build system able to remote compile and link via SSH?

Currently for cross platform development I am using git pull/push but is not really the best option for me, I was wondering if there is any build system for c++ who know to do that out of the box.

Comment: Why this question is marked "off topic"? From the help center: `We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers ... software tools commonly used by programmers ... then you’re in the right place to ask your question!` So here is a question about tools for programming, what is wrong with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is!

https://github.com/distcc/distcc

`distcc` is able to compile on any remote system, where the selected compiler is installed. The source will be distributed to all the remote hosts, compiled there and the error and warning messages are send back. This enables you also to compile on multiple remote hosts to get all the performance of all the connected build hosts. Quite simple to setup a build farm with `distcc`.

You simple have to setup a distcc environment with make or simply by setting the environment vars for your build system. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Distcc#Slaves

Maybe as a remark: distcc is not a build system but simply a replacement for your local compiler. E.g. replacing gcc with distcc and setting up the remote hosts will do the job. The build system itself ( like `gnu make` ) stay unchanged!

Comment: Thanks for the link, I have to check to check for documentation, sounds like an option to me.